# Why is it that objects inside a moving train tend to move at the same speed as the train itself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, time, velocity, speed

I mean I get people saying because it's Newtonian mechanics. Everything inside the train will have same speed as that of train but my question is why ? Why is it like that ? And How does that happen ?
Even if you say that let's say you and train kind of like become a system if you're let's say like sitting in the train. Even if you jump in the train. Still... You are moving at the same speed as that of train.
Why doesn't the air move backwards towards the back of train ?
Could u help in giving me a detailed explanation and a picture ?

Comment: One can play catch (baseball) inside a train moving at a constant velocity on a straight line just fine. Galileo had figured this out around 1630, except that he didn't have trains back then, so he used a ship for this example. In modern terms this is known as "the relativity principle" and it's responsible for most of the structure of physics. So your premise is already wrong and not just by a little. It's so wrong that it destroys the foundations of physics.

Answer (score 2):

Contact forces between the interior of the train and the objects within will generally keep the whole system moving at the same speed. Of course in principle if you had an infinitely long train and no friction everything would shoot backwards in the rest frame of the train.

Comment: Why ? Why doesn't the air gets pushed back in the train to the back side ?

Comment: @S.M.T  The air is an extra condition you are introducing. fluid dynamics

Comment: @S.M.T yes the air molecules do form a slight gradient in a container that accelerates to uniform velocity. You can see this in how a helium balloon moves forwards in an accelerating car due to this very gradient. But this is fine, if the container accelerates, the air molecules won't know until they impact the back or other molecules that already have done so.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of [Newton's first law of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton%27s_first_law). As long as the train is travelling at a constant speed in a straight line, and everything within it is also travelling at a constant speed in a straight line, then no forces are required to maintain this state of motion.

Newton's first law of motion is based on empirical observations. If your question is "why does Newton's first law of motion hold in our world ?" then we have no idea, and physics does not address this question.

It is certainly possible to create a consistent set of physical laws in which there is a preferred stationary reference frame, and everything that is in motion relative to this reference frame requires a force to keep it in motion - but that would be a radically different world to the one we experience. For example, all of the planets would slow down in their orbits without a tangential force to keep them moving - so the solar system (and, indeed, the whole galaxy) would stop moving and collapse under its own gravity.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to consider a bus. If you open the back window and some at the front then there will definitively be a draft going backwards. When all the windows are closed and the bus accelerates, there will be a momentary movement of the air to back of the bus (The air is momentarily stationary and the bus is moving forward from the pint of view of a bystander on the sidewalk.) The air compresses to back and some of it compresses and bounces of the rear window and those molecules bounce off other air molecules accelerating them forward to eventually match the speed of the bus. Unfortunately buses do not normally accelerate fast enough for this effect to be noticeable.

If you jump in the train, you initially have the velocity of train from when you were standing. The air is comoving with the train so there is nothing pushing you backwards while you are in the air and continue to travel at the same velocity as the train while in the air. Not that in this case the air is not pushing you forward while you are in the air. Its just a simple fact of physics that everything continues at its current velocity until something slows it down.